# vba run time error 9 subscript out of range

Tags: vba

Я вызываю метод с main_report - название файла

```
Sub main(main_report, semi_report, period)
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbb = Workbooks(parse_name(main_report))
...
```

и получаю ошибку run time error 9

сама функция parse_name

```
Function parse_name(wb_name)
listik = Split(wb_name, ".")
new_name = ""
For i = 0 To UBound(listik) - 1
    new_name = new_name & listik(i) & "."
Next i
new_name = Left(new_name, Len(new_name) - 1)
parse_name = new_name
End Function
```

Comment: Что -то странное Вы делаете...В функции разбиваете `wb_name` на отдельные слова, без точек (точка - разделитель), потом в цикле объединяете эти слова через точку - получаете исходное значение, которое передавали в функцию, но без последней точки. Ошибка возникает, видимо, при попытке засунуть в переменную книгу с непонятным именем. Опишите задачу, которую пытаетесь решить.

Comment: *получаю ошибку run time error 9* В какой хоть строке кода?

Comment: Не заметил - удаляется последнее слово из строки. Но все равно, без описания задачи по ошибке больше нечего сказать. А для удаления последнего слова вместо функци достаточно одной строки: `wb_name = Left$(wb_name, InStrRev(wb_name, ".") - 1)`